# Python concurrent.futures threadpoolexecutor thread management

Tags: python, fastapi, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I have a FastAPI app having one API which needs to run some tasks in parallel. I Have implemented threadpoolexecutor and it's working fine. The only problem is everytime a request comes to that API and execution comes to threadpool executor, it creates new threads instead of using the old one. Upon finishing the execution, threads are still present and idle. They are not getting closed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved now.
The problem was that in the **init**  I was calling the playwright.start() method which starts some connection but the stop method was not being called in teardown.